# Which development skill/path will add more benefit/value to QA

Tags: learning, career-development, front-end, back-end

I'm a QA, now I have a chance to learn a development skill under developer instruction. Which one will add more benefit for a QA career path?

- Back-end (PHP)
- Front-end

Please help to shed a light

Comment: What is your goal to be ? A tester or a developer ?

Comment: My answer is a tester, I'm trying to figure out which one will add more benefit to my current (QA) career path

Comment: In automation or in manual?

Comment: I need both of them. Could you please give an advice ?

Comment: See there are two approach and both of them are good. As per my exp you should go for front end development first. If you think HTML, CSS and JS are already known properly by you then go for PHP. And try to learn  logical things and problem solving ability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends, both paths back-end and front-end have their testing challenges.

I would start with front-end, because understanding the basics of a web-application is very useful when when creating end-2-end UI-automation tests with for example Selenium/WebDriver. As Selenium/WebDriver is the facto standard this makes this most sense from a career perspective.

Learning how the back-end works later might also be easier if you understand how the front-end access API's and such.

**Go full-stack:**

Best would be to learn and create a simple full-stack application in your training. So including back-end and front-end, but also including all the automated tests that you typically need coverage for: Unit-tests, Integration tests and Functional end-2-end test. Understanding the full life-cycle was very helpful for me.